# Uncaught Error: Could not compile HighlightDirective because it is not a component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

**Error Log:**

> runtime_compiler.js:353Uncaught Error: Could not compile 'HighlightDirective' because it is not a component.assertComponent
>   ...

**Directive:**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[dirHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer :Renderer) {

  //this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement,'background-color', 'green');
  }
```

}

**Html file:**

```
<h2> Custom Attribute Directive</h2>
<div dirHighlight> Some thing</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'dir-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  entryComponents:[HighlightDirective],

})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add Directives in the Main Module you have, not as `entryComponents`

```
import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HighlightDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Look at the documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#write-directive)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, removing the entryComponent from app.component. ts worked for me.